# Узнать, запущена ли активити из сервиса

Tags: android, activity, android-service

Как можно из сервиса узнать, запущена ли активити и в зависимости от этого показывать/не показывать уведомление?

Comment: пускай активити при запуске в onCreate кидает специальный броадкаст, а сервис слушает систему на его наличие.и аналогично броадкаст при activity onDestroy при закрытии активити. ну а внутри сервиса какой-то флажок открыта/не открыта, изменяющийся в зависимости от приходящего броадкаста

Comment: распишите немного подробнее - у меня есть код сервиса в который передается интерфейс, и уже активности реализуют интерфейс по разному, есть и вариант когда сервис работает в фоновом режиме, и сообщения идут именно интерфейсу. возможно вам именно такой вариант и нужен?

Comment: @EvgenOrlovsky сервис работает в фоне, в определённый момент ему нужно показать уведомление, если активность не запущена.

Comment: @Evgeniy привел в качестве ответа свою функцию отправки сообщений из сервиса - сервис работает в фоновом режиме. Если понадобится - могу весь код сервиса выложить.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создаёте свой класс `Application`, реализуете в нём интерфейс `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` и регистрируете в качестве слушателя. И в нём отслеживаете какие активити были открыты или закрыты:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application 
        implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

    private int activityCount = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();    
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    public boolean isAppForeground() {
        return activityCount > 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        activityCount++;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
        activityCount--;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }
}
```

И когда нужно, в сервисе получаете аппликейшн и проверяете, открыто ли приложение:

```
((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).isAppForeground();
```

Не забудьте объявить ваш класс аппликейшн в манифесте:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        ...
>
....
</application>
```

Если вам нужно отследить только какую-то конкретную активити, проверяйте в соответствующих методах тип класса `if (activity instanceof YourTargetActivity)`:

```
public boolean isTargetActivityStarted = false;

@Override
public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
    if (activity instanceof YourTargetActivity) {
        isTargetActivityStarted = true;
    }
}

@Override
public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    if (activity instanceof YourTargetActivity) {
        isTargetActivityStarted = false;
    }
}
```

И в сервисе проверяете переменную:

```
if (((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).isTargetActivityStarted) {
    // Активити запущена и находится на переднем плане
} else {
    // Активити не запущена или свёрнута
}
```

Comment: Можно поподробней про "Если вам нужно отследить только какую-то конкретную активити" ?

Comment: @Evgeniy дополнил ответ, смотрите

Answer (score 0):

Немного частный случай, но как вариант можно:

В сервисе отправлять `Broadcast`

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public static final String ACTION_FILTER = "com.exampe.EVENT";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_FILTER);
        intent.putExtra(...);
        sendOrderedBroadcast(intent, null);
    }
}
```

Зарегистрировать `receiver` в `AndroidManifest.xml` с низким приоритетом

```
<receiver
    android:name=".services.NotificationsReceiver"
    android:priority="0">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.exampe.EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

В нем отправлять уведомление

В `Activity` в `OnResume()` зарегистрировать `receiver` с высоким приоритетом, на `OnPause()` отрегистрировать.

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(MessagingService.ACTION_FILTER);
intentFilter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

И в этом `receiver`'е делать, то что нужно когда `Activity` запущена

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //do something
        abortBroadcast(); //отменяет дальнейшую обработку бродкаста
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

сервис может посылать уведомления через Notification

пример кода - из моего проекта:

```
public void sendMessage(int countNews){
    Resources resources = getResources();
    Intent i = NewsListActivity.newIntent(this);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

    Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setTicker(resources.getString(R.string.get_new_news))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif_logo)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setNumber(countNews)
            .setContentTitle(resources.getString(R.string.get_new_news))
            .setContentText(resources.getQuantityString(R.plurals.news_plurals, countNews, countNews))
            .setContentIntent(pi)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

в intent пакуется активность которая будет запущена при нажатии на уведомлении.

Answer (score 0):

Определить запущен ли активити на экране не сложно

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    _show_form = false;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    _show_form = false;
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    _show_form = true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume () {
    super.onResume();
    _show_form = true;
}
```